# exec() function is returning None

Tags: python

I have a very simple program, which calculates an equation:

```py
calc = "3 + 18 / 6 * 12 - 2"
ans = exec(calc)
print(ans)
```

I would like this to print `37`, but instead, it returns `None`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using the [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function instead, it's for evaluating _expressions_, which is what you appear to be trying to do.

Comment: Be very careful when using exec/eval, you should never pass any user input to these functions

Comment: @martineau That works. I've never used ```eval()``` before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working as expected. [The documentation for `exec`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#exec) *clearly* states:

> The return value is `None`.

You might want to use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval):

> The return value is the result of the evaluated expression.

However, for both `exec` and `eval`, you should make 150% sure that you only process *trusted* and *safe* input. In general, it would be much better to *parse* and *evaluate* the expression yourself.